# Open Source Online IDE

Tags: php, javascript, open-source, ide, mootools

Are there any Open Source online IDE's except for Bespin?

If found some online IDE's like; phpanywhere.net, coderun.com, squadedit.com, codepad.org, but non of them are open source.

Bespin isn't working for me, it could be because I'm a Opera user, but even in Firefox I couldn't get it to work properly. And if there is no other alternative; what about creating a new open source project?

---

*First, if I'm supposed to create an open source project; what would be the best place to host it?
Any of these?
 - http://github.com/
 - http://code.google.com/hosting/
 - http://sourceforge.net/*

I went with the github solution.

---

I'm thinking of creating this with php and the JavaScript framework MooTools.

What would be the best way to build the code editing area on?

- html textarea-tag
- html iframe-tag
- creating an own enging like [google did](https://drive.googleblog.com/2010/05/whats-different-about-new-google-docs.html) with google docs?

Theres also the html5 option, like Bespin did. But the problem there is that its not working. Also another reason for that I don't want to go for Bespin is that its an dead prosject. As far as I know several of the team members that worked at Bespin now work for other companies.

Also, I'm thinking about building it upon the "Operational transformation" as google did. But should I first create that as an separate Open Source prosject? An Operational transformation javascript implementation for MooTools.

Comment: come to #mootools on irc.freenode.net and talk to zalun (piotr) - he is the creator of http://www.jsfiddle.net (which is as close to an online ide as you can get to) and now works at mozilla (because of jsfiddle) on bespin and jetpack.

Comment: I'd recommend you stick to one question per... well, question. Create a new Question if you want to know something about another topic (like hosting your project) or add to your question if you require additional info about the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could help yourself with [Codemirror](http://codemirror.net/), there are already a few examples written.

Comment: Thanks, seems like an good solution. I will probably use that one for code highlighting.

Comment: We're using CodeMirror down at http://jsfiddle.net - thought a lot about the perfect solution and CodeMirror was the best option, Bespin was WAY too buggy back then. Currently Bespin has been rewritten from scratch and used in https://builder.mozillalabs.com/ (by design, the site works on Firefox only).

Answer (score 0):

Kodingen is no more.

It's now [Koding](http://koding.com) and it's miles away from where Kodingen was. Free VM with root. I think that says enough.